# Why does assigning with a strong property work, but not with a weak one?

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references

I have a property declared in my .h file as

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIPickerView *levelPicker;
```

which is synthezised in my implementation file as:

```
@synthesize levelPicker = _levelPicker;
```

I then have a code block in the same implementation file which does the following:

```
if (self.levelPicker == nil) {
    self.levelPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.levelPicker.delegate = self;
    self.levelPicker.dataSource = self;
}
textField.inputView = self.levelPicker;
```

In this case, self._levelPicker is not set to the new UIPickerView.  I.e. the self.levelPicker = blah assignment doesn't work.

However, if I change the property declaration to:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPickerView *levelPicker;
```

then everything works as expected and _levelPicker is set to the newly allocated UIPickerView.

Can someone please tell me why this is the case?  I thought I was coming to an understanding of how references work, but I guess I still have more to learn.  I read some of the other related SO posts, but it's still not entirely clear to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Inazfiger says, your objects need at least one strong (retaining) reference, otherwise they won't be retained.

In this case, you're assigning the picker view to a `UITextField`'s `inputView` property. The text field will retain the picker view (I know this because the `inputView` property on `UITextField` is [declared with the modifiers "readwrite, **retain**"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/inputView)), but **only once you've made the assignment**. So if you want to stick with a weak reference, you need to rearrange your code slightly - something like this:

```
// Declare a temporary UIPickerView reference. By default, this is
// a strong reference - so tempPicker will be retained until this
// variable goes out of scope.
UIPickerView *tempPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

// Configure the picker
tempPicker.delegate = self;
tempPicker.dataSource = self;

// Assign the picker view to the text field's inputView property. This
// will increase the picker's retain count. Now it'll no longer be
// released when tempPicker goes out of scope.
textField.inputView = tempPicker;

// Finally, assign the same object to self.levelPicker - it won't
// go out of scope as long as it remains assigned to textField's
// inputView property, and textField itself remains retained.
self.levelPicker = tempPicker;
```

Comment: Couldn't you just skip the temporary variable and assign it directly to the inputview before it goes out of scope?

Comment: You could write `textField.inputView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]` and then configure textField.inputView directly, but I try to avoid that in case the property I'm assigning to (inputView in this case) has a custom setter with logic that relies on the state of the object being assigned.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for.  Thanks, and thanks to @Inafziger, too.  I guess a further question would be: Is there any advantage to using a weak reference here, or should I just be using a strong one?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you are wanting from this code.  If you want (as I suspect) levelPicker to keep a reference to the object at all times, even if it isn't being used anywhere else at the moment, then you should use a strong reference.  Make sure to set it to nil when you no longer need it though (often in viewDidUnload)!

Answer (score 4):

Well, the short answer is that the assignment actually does work.

However, since it is a weak reference, it isn't retained since there is no (other) strong reference to your picker and it is automatically set to nil.

There has to be at least one strong reference to any object otherwise it isn't retained, which in this case there isn't.

For more information, see "[ARC Introduces New Lifetime Qualifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226)" in Apple's "Transitioning to ARC Release Notes".

Ray Wenderlich created a great tutorial on this [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1).

Answer (score 1):

The "strong" qualifier creates an owner relationship that stops the object being deallocated, which is equivalent what you would do in the non-ARC world previously:

```
@property(retain) NSObject *obj;
```

While "weak" qualifier doesn't create the owner relationship so the object will be deallocated as you would do before:

```
@property(assign) NSObject *obj;
```

In your case, you need the first relationship because you need your instance variable (_levelPicker) to hold on to the newly created UIPickerView instance. The weak assignment you did actually work but it was deallocated shortly after.